# ¿Cómo descontar del inventario los productos que estan proximos a vencer?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo 3 tablas relacionadas en mi BD inventario:

1. producto (`idProducto` int(11) NOT NULL, `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL, `medida` varchar(30) NOT NULL, `existencia` decimal(11,3) NOT NULL)
2. entrada (`idEntrada` int(11) NOT NULL, `producto` int(11) NOT NULL, `fecha_entrada` date NOT NULL, `cantidad_entrada` decimal(11,3) NOT NULL, `fecha_vencimiento` date NOT NULL, `cantidad_utilizada` decimal(11,3) NOT NULL)
3. salida (`idSalida` int(11) NOT NULL, `producto` int(11) NOT NULL, `fecha_salida` date NOT NULL, `cantidad_salida` decimal(11,3) NOT NULL)

Estos son los datos que tengo en cada tabla:

```
INSERT INTO `producto` (`idProducto`, `nombre`, `medida`, `existencia`) VALUES (1, 'arroz', 'kg', '25.000'), (2, 'avena', 'kg', '0.000'), (3, 'leche', 'lt', '0.000'), (4, 'Queso', 'kg', '0.000');

INSERT INTO `entrada` (`idEntrada`, `producto`, `fecha_entrada`, `cantidad_entrada`, `fecha_vencimiento`, `cantidad_utilizada`) VALUES (1, 1, '2022-06-06', '10.000', '2022-07-16', '0.000'), (2, 1, '2022-06-18', '5.000', '2022-06-18', '0.000'), (3, 1, '2022-06-07', '12.000', '2022-07-09', '0.000');

INSERT INTO `salida` (`idSalida`, `producto`, `fecha_salida`, `cantidad_salida`) VALUES (1, 1, '2022-06-13', '2.000');
```

Cuando registro la entrada / salida de algún producto, lo hago con PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
$consulta = $mysqli->query("UPDATE producto SET existencia = existencia + '$cantidad' WHERE idProducto = '$producto'");

$consulta = $mysqli->query("UPDATE producto SET existencia = existencia - '$cantidad' WHERE idProducto = '$producto'");
```

Hasta arriba todo bien, pero me gustaría especificar dónde se va haciendo el descuento. Y que además eso se haga según la fecha de vencimiento del producto. Por ejemplo:

[image: tabla_inventario]

Según la tabla *Entradas* que aparece en la imagen, 5 kg son los más próximos a vencer. Entonces, ya que utilicé 2 kg, ahora debería aparecer 3 kg en *Entradas*, porque ya se descontó esa cantidad de la existencia. Tengo más o menos la lógica para lograr esto, pero no estoy seguro de cómo codificarlo o si hay una mejor manera de obtener lo que necesito... había pensado en lo siguiente:

1. Cada vez que inserte alguna salida, guardo el id del producto y la cantidad
2. Luego obtengo el id y la cantidad de entrada con la fecha de vencimiento mas cercana... tengo esta consulta para eso: `SELECT idEntrada, cantidad_entrada FROM entrada WHERE fecha_entrada = ( SELECT MAX(fecha_entrada) FROM entrada WHERE producto = 1)`
3. Aquí tenía pensado hacer una comparación... si cantidad_salida <= cantidad_entrada realizo un UPDATE en la tabla *entrada* de mi BD, esto para actualizar el campo *cantidad_utilizada* dónde colocaría  cantidad_salida. Y luego resto cantidad_entrada - cantidad_utilizada para obtener lo que queda. Ahora si cantidad_salida > cantidad_entrada tendría que descontar lo que tengo y luego obtener la siguiente entrada con fecha más reciente, que según el ejemplo serían los 12 kg. Creo que esto último se hace con un ciclo while pero no se me ocurre cómo estructurarlo...
   Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con esto :c

Comment: Si es para un sistema productivo, el manejo de caducidades tiene más retos, por ejemplo: ¿Todos los productos tienen la misma caducidad?. Si es para un sistema de práctica, se valen muchas cosas, incluso guardar cálculos; tu inventario en tiempo real se puede reducir a todas las entradas menos todas las salidas de cada producto.

Comment: Como ve puede apreciar en la imagen, no todos los productos tienen la misma caducidad... justamente por eso quiero descontar los que están próximos a vencer. Y estoy practicando, pero tampoco es que quiera hacer "trampa", solo busco una manera de obtener lo que necesito de la mejor manera posible

Comment: ¿Tienes la posibilidad de cambiar la estructura de las tablas? Pregunto porque, de ser así, una tabla que administre entradas/salidas/remanente sería una solución muchísimo mas sencilla.

Comment: @Liyo No puedo eliminar ninguna de las 3 tablas que tengo, pero sí le puedo añadir y/o eliminar los campos que tienen. También agregar otra tabla... aunque no sé si sea necesario

Comment: @Leoddy A mi entender, almacenar el stock remanente en la tabla Entradas para cada entrada, es de gran ayuda para luego hacer `SELECT * FROM Entradas WHERE remanete > 0 ORDER BY fecha_vencimiento desc`. Tal vez utilizar una tabla temporal para guardar esos registros e ir descontando el stock de acuerdo a las salidas y al stock remanente de cada fila. Espero haberme explicado bien, sino me dices.

Comment: Caso contrario, no almacenas en ningún lado la cantidad que restas de cada entrada. Podrías descontar directamente de la entrada, pero en ese caso, si haces un `UPDATE` de la `cantidad_entrada`, no te queda registro de ese ingreso para consultas futuras sobre ingresos.

Comment: Hay una forma de resolver técnicamente la consulta. Pero nunca responderá a la realidad. Al menos tal y como tienes las tablas configuradas. En la vida real, los descuentos por vencimiento son salidas específicas de un tipo determinado (hay salidas por ventas, por consumo, por vencimiento, etc.) Si aún así quieres seguir con tu planteamiento, deberías añadir también la `fecha_vencimiento` a tus salidas. Porque das por supuesto que siempre serán las más antiguas, pero esto no es matemático. Por no hablar de que a veces entra arroz con f_vencimiento de 2022-05-05 y mañana quizá de 2021-04-04